# Session cookie not send back by client using URLConnection in windows with JRE 1.7

Tags: java, windows, session-cookies, java-web-start, urlconnection

We have an application that is deploied using Java Web Start. It communicate with a servlet using URLConnection and managing session by Cookies  (JSESSIONID).
It worked well with Java 1.5 & 1.6. With Java 1.7 in **windows** It doesn't work anymore: cookie JSESSIONID is not send back to the server (I saw this using apache axis's HTTPMonitor). What's going wrong?

Launching the same application with Java Web Start from a linux box works as expected.

Version are: JRE 1.7.0_04 with Java Web Start 10.4.0.22_04

Comment: Check the bug DB.  If you don't find a related bug, raise one.

Comment: Added to bug db. I had found a similar problem on oracle forums but the post is now desapperead. Someone has experienced the same problem?

Comment: The bug has been fixed in last release of JRE

Comment: For reference (from a deleted answer) http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7176662

Answer (score 2):

We were getting incredibly frustrated with the fact that our application worked fine when launched from Eclipse but failed to communicate with our authenticated REST endpoints, when run via Web Start, due to the JSESSIONID going missing as per the problem described in the question. We are running Java 1.7.

After much remote debugging, we discovered that whether intentional or not (I can only find little documentation on it, e.g. a one-liner here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/cookiehandler.html), a Java Web Start application sets a default CookieHandler, usually an instance of `com.sun.deploy.net.cookie.DeployCookieSelector`, but whatever this is, this messes up the JSESSIONID cookie handling. Reset the default cookie handler to null `java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(null)` and voila, the outgoing HTTP requests have the JSESSIONID cookie preserved!

BTW Windows and Linux both exhibited this behaviour.